# Differences between NULL and zero-length in database

Tags: relational-database

My project uses Microsoft SQL Server Express 2019 as data-engine and potentially will be migrated to other data-engine.

The database used in the vb.net Desktop application.

Tables usually contain an optional field "Note".

By design of the app can be used "record has no note" or "record has a zero-length note".

In VB second variant even a little bit simplifies code, but what is better to store in the database NULL or zero-length string as non-nullable text.

Primary I'm interested in speed-optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any speed difference is likely to be incredibly subtle, and whose importance could only depend on extremely large volumes, particular kinds of operation, and the specific implementation (so it could vary between technologies).

I would suggest you focus instead on whether there is any semantic distinction in your application between an "empty note" and "no note" - if not, then just pick an option and run with it consistently in your application.

I would also say this confounding case arises more often when note storage is not properly normalised. That is, where a note is optional, but it is stored inline as a field (and expressed in the UI as a single fixed field) rather than as a separate table which can express zero or many notes (with associated UI functionality which allows the option to add notes as necessary).

Comment: I have registration journals - something like "paper prototype" of tables, where about 80% rows have some notes like "done", "fail", email, phone number, etc. If users will use an app in a similar way it better to have a separate column and textbox for notes like on paper, right?

Comment: @BogdanSamchuk, if your app closely reflects a paper process (or has a fallback to paper, or data entry from paper) where there is a fixed space for notes, then yes arguably it is better to denormalise and be consistent with the paper forms. The paper equivalent of normalised notes, is something akin to applying/stapling post-it notes to a master sheet, scribbling or marking in blank areas, or adding supplementary note sheets to a file/bundle. (1/2)

Comment: It's a known problem with paper forms that many are designed not to distinguish between the absence of information given (a NULL), and a positively blank answer (a ZLS). It doesn't always matter, but sometimes it does if the organisation will want to react differently to information not given (for example, by rejecting the data as invalid, or storing a part-complete entry pending further information), than to blank information (such as where a valid address has certain elements missing, like the absence of a street number for a property that is addressed only by name). (2/2)

Answer (score 5):

> "Primary I'm interested in speed-optimization"

This is the wrong question.

I would bet 100 bucks blindly that in your system, performance-wise it does not matter, and will not matter (without knowing your system).

What matters is if using the either or other variant forces you to write more code to deal with special cases. For a "note" field which is storing just explanatory text strings, not expected to become part of a foreign key, I would usually prefer the "zero-length" string variant. It has the advantage that operations like determining the average length of a note, sorting by notes, or string concatenations won't require additional SQL functions to deal with the NULL case.

I can imagine, however, cases where the "empty string" is a special, extraordinary case which maps more natural to NULL, because, one *want* to deal with it in a specific manner. For example, when the string in stake is an optional  foreign key, a zero length string may be disallowed by the database, but a NULL field may be allowed.  So the decision here may be a different one.

I found [this short article](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/null-vs-empty-zero-length-string/) containing more detailed information about the topic.